# Can a SonarQube be accessed from public network?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have a SonarQube 6.1 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and i want to access it from public network.

I have done port forwarding on GW router, i get the login page but i get authentication failed after submitting the credentials.

The same credentials work ok from localhost.

I have also tried to run it behind nginx as proxy(like described here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Running+SonarQube+behind+a+Proxy) but still the same error.

The SonarQube install and config is nothing special, setting up to use MySql and enabling user authentication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your Server base URL configured, something like `http://GW:port/` ?

Comment: I get the same result(authentication failed) when setting sonar.web.host to 'http://GW:port/' or 'http://GW', or just not setting it.